# Rewrite URL with one unnecessary parameter

Tags: htaccess, apache, modx

I have the following URL examples. Example one is a URL without "amps" parameter:
`https://multilang:8890/uk/seconddoc.html/` there I have a 404 error. And an other one with that amps parameter that works just fine: `https://multilang:8890/uk/seconddoc.html/amps`
The amps parameter can be present or not present. Here is my .htaccess rule for overwriting this

```sh
RewriteRule ^(ru|en|uk|)/(.*)/(amps)$ index.php?cultureKey=$1&q=$2&amps [QSA]
```

How can I rewrite those URLs so that example 1 and example 2 will direct to a same page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the "amps" in the URL optional by adding a `?` to the regex in the correct spot.  Also because regex are greedy, you shouldn't accept slashes in the middle of your URL.  Use `[^/]*` instead of `.*`:

```sh
RewriteRule ^(ru|en|uk|)/([^/]*)/(amps)?$ index.php?cultureKey=$1&q=$2&amps [QSA]
```

You might also want to not pass "amps" as a parameter if it isn't in the URL.  To do that, you could use a third capturing variable (`$3`):

```sh
RewriteRule ^(ru|en|uk|)/([^/]*)/(amps)?$ index.php?cultureKey=$1&q=$2&$3 [QSA]
```

You might also want to make the trailing slash optional so that `https://multilang:8890/uk/seconddoc.html` works:

```sh
RewriteRule ^(ru|en|uk|)/([^/]*)(/(amps)?)?$ index.php?cultureKey=$1&q=$2&$4 [QSA]
```